# What is wrong with this using this string Literal?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to assign this string literal to a string variable.

```
 String myString = @"<h1 style=""font-family: Sans-Serif; font-size: 1.2em; 
 color: #dedede;border-bottom: solid 1px #dedede;"">Issue</h1><br>;"
```

I get an error stating the following:

**Method Name Expected**

I have tried using the forward slash "/" with no sucess. The VS ide complains right under font-family.

```
 String myString = @"<h1 style=/"font-family: Sans-Serif; font-size: 1.2em; color: 
 #dedede;border-bottom: solid 1px #dedede;/">Issue</h1><br>"
```

Using this produces the following error:

**";" Expected**

Comment: The backslash (" \ ") is the escape character in C#. However, it ignored when you use the @ literal in front of a string. The @ is mostly to avoid mangling URLs/paths or `Regex` patterns.

Comment: @ENC0D3D please don't edit your question with answers, otherwise it falsifies your question, unless you point out what you have edited.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is nothing wrong with your first statement except the fact that you are missing a semicolon at the end, which marks statement end.

```
String myString = @"<h1 style=""font-family: Sans-Serif; font-size: 1.2em; 
color: #dedede;border-bottom: solid 1px #dedede;"">Issue</h1><br>";
                                                              ///^^^^ here
```

You don't need forward slash to escape double quotes, It is back slash which is used to escape characters. But since you are using `@` *(Verbatim string)* with your string, you need an extra double quote `"` to escape the existing double quote. *(which you are doing correctly in your first version)*

Comment: Stack-overflow, finding missing semi-colon's since 2008. lol :)

Comment: Not so fast.  It still gives the same "method name expected" error.

Comment: @ENC0D3D, No it does not. Just copied the same thing in visual studio and it compiles fine. Are you sure you are getting the error on the same line ? also try clean/rebuild your application.

Comment: @ENC0D3D you put the `;` in the wrong place. needs to be outside the `"`

Comment: @TimBJames, that is good catch, This semicolon came after the question was ghost edited. But the OP put it inside quotes :)

Comment: @Habib yeah I was on the page when it happened so noticed the edit ;)

Comment: I think the "method" error threw me off....Thanks All!!!! ;)

Comment: Find one semicolon,get nine vote,just ironic...